# A2DP streaming from android using AAC/mp3 codec

Tags: android, default, codec, aac, a2dp

As we know that the default coded used for streaming audio in A2DP is SBC, but the sound quality is not good. A2Dp profile supports optional codec like mp3, aac, and atrac. So i have the following questions:

1) Is there any android phone in market which usages aac or mp3 for A2DP streaming ? 
2) Provided a phone supports mp3/aac codec for A2DP streaming, how do we change the default
   codec from SBC to other codec? 
3) how do we enable this in google nexus 4?

i am using google nexus 4 running android 4.2.2.
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your all questions are answered @ [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26410/how-do-i-determine-which-a2dp-codecs-my-phone-supports-is-currently-using)

In android now stack is changed from bluez to bludroid so change may not be that easy, APTx codec is also widely used for audio streaming